# "Run-time error '13' only when "Fill down" used?

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

The following code is designed to only allow an entry of 1, 2 or 3 in the range of cells. If something else is entered, an error message pops up and the entry is undone. The code works perfectly unless the user fills down their response. At that point, a "run-time error '13'" comes up. I would like the users to be able to fill down their entries, is there a way around this error?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    If Not Intersect(Target, [T7:AE61]) Is Nothing Then
    If (Target.Value Like "1") Then
    ElseIf (Target.Value Like "2") Then
    ElseIf (Target.Value Like "3") Then
    ElseIf (Not Target.Value Like "") Then
          MsgBox "Please enter a rating of 1, 2 or 3."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
      End If

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any possible help!

Comment: Any particular reason you're rolling your own solution using VBA instead of using Excel's built in data validation that does exactly this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When They perform a fill Down, `Target` is a range with multiple cells.  So, `Target.Value Like "1"` fails because you are attempting to compare a variant array with a string.  What you need to do is process individual cells within the target range one at a time.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range    'Added line

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    If Not Intersect(Target, [A1:AE61]) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, [A1:AE61])    'Added line
            'Within this loop, I have replaced Target with cell
            If (cell.Value Like "1") Then
            ElseIf (cell.Value Like "2") Then
            ElseIf (cell.Value Like "3") Then
            ElseIf (Not cell.Value Like "") Then
                MsgBox "Please enter a rating of 1, 2 or 3."
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Application.Undo

                Application.EnableEvents = True

            End If
        Next cell    'Added line
    End If

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! A simple cut and paste works perfectly. Your logic makes perfect sense - now I just need to hunker down and figure out the code changes so I can learn something today. :) Thank you!